# Azure blob trigger python function executes multiple times for each subfolder and creates multiple copies of the file

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

1. monitoring container input/landing
2. .json file arrives in a format yy/mm/DD/myfile.json
3. if valid json file --> move it to input/staging/.json
4. if not valid --> copy to input/rejected/.json

Function triggers multiple times for each subfolder and output folder has 3 copies of the same file.
How to modify function to only trigger once and only copy file once?

import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json

**my **init**.py**

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, inputBlob: bytes, outputBlob1: func.Out[bytes], outputBlob2: func.Out[bytes]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    # Read the contents of the input blob
    blob_content = myblob.read()
    processed_file = validateJSON(blob_content) # returns True or False

    # if pass json validation 
    if processed_file:
        outputBlob1.set(myblob.read())
        logging.info(f"Blob copied to outputBlob1: {myblob.name}")
    else:
        outputBlob2.set(myblob.read())
        logging.info(f"Blob copied to outputBlob2: {myblob.name}")

# func to validate json data (not file!)
def validateJSON(jsonData):
    try:
        json.loads(jsonData)
    except ValueError as err:
        return False
    return True
```

**my function.json file:**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/landing/{name}",
      "connection": "mystorageaccount"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/landing/{name}",
      "connection": "mystorageaccount"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob1",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "input/staging/{rand-guid}.json",
      "connection": "mystorageaccount"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob2",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "input/regected/{rand-guid}.json",
      "connection": "mystorageaccount"
    }
  ]
}
```

**my terminal output:**

```
[2023-07-08T14:44:03.452Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000FA91B3A1'.
[2023-07-08T14:46:27.618Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): input/landing/2023/07',

[2023-07-08T14:46:28.031Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: input/landing/2023/07
Blob Size: None bytes
[2023-07-08T14:46:28.164Z] Blob copied to outputBlob2: input/landing/2023/07
[2023-07-08T14:46:28.282Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): input/landing/2023/07/08', 

[2023-07-08T14:46:28.485Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: input/landing/2023/07/08
Blob Size: None bytes[2023-07-08T14:46:28.500Z] Blob copied to outputBlob2: input/landing/2023/07/08

[2023-07-08T14:46:28.991Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=6a6e5f58-b49e-46c9-a019-c8814c87e5fb, Duration=1656ms)
[2023-07-08T14:46:29.166Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=cfe1f858-fe5e-46cd-85fd-281fff7a0204, Duration=1057ms)
[2023-07-08T14:46:29.330Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): input/landing/2023/07/08/invalidJSON.json', Id=5a81c13f-b633-4be1-bdac-7281389f4403)

[2023-07-08T14:46:29.629Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: input/landing/2023/07/08/invalidJSON.json
Blob Size: None bytes
[2023-07-08T14:46:29.629Z] Blob copied to outputBlob2: input/landing/2023/07/08/invalidJSON.json
[2023-07-08T14:46:30.211Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=5a81c13f-b633-4be1-bdac-7281389f4403, Duration=1157ms)
```

**result: multiple copies**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Azure blob trigger python function executes multiple times for each subfolder and creates multiple copies of the file

I have reproduced in my environment and below is the code which worked worked for me:

**`function.json:`**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "path": "samples-workitems/land/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blobTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob1",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "path": "samples-workitems/approved/{rand-guid}.json"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob2",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "path": "samples-workitems/rejected/{rand-guid}.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`init.py:`**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json

 

def main(myblob: func.InputStream, outputBlob1: func.Out[bytes], outputBlob2: func.Out[bytes]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

 

    blob_content1 = myblob.read()
    processed_file = validateJSON(blob_content1)  # returns True or False

 

    # if pass json validation
    if processed_file:
        outputBlob1.set(blob_content1)
        logging.info(f"Blob copied to outputBlob1: {myblob.name}")
    else:
        outputBlob2.set(blob_content1)
        logging.info(f"Blob copied to outputBlob2: {myblob.name}")

 

    

 

# func to validate json data (not file!)
def validateJSON(jsonData1):
    try:
        json.loads(jsonData1)
    except ValueError as err:
        return False
    return True
```

**`Output:`**

**`If Success:`**

[image]

[image]
**`If rejected:`**

[image]

[image]

This is the code and process which worked for me try to change `function.json`(i have observerd 4 bindings, make it to 3) and `init` file(why are you using inputblob remove it) according to mine. Try to change your code and you will get desired output as i have got

Comment: Thanks. But in myblob has daily drops a folder with json file (not just  a file). So every day "input/landing" will receive a dynamic folder "2023/08/08/.json. That is why function executes multiple times (for each folder and subfolder)

Comment: But seems like simply adding .json extension in function.json file does the trick. 
`"path": "input/landing/{name}.json",`

Comment: Yes, you are correct that does the trick. Follow my code and you will get output as I have got.